# query result echoing results four times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a functioning query that is echoing the correct results, for 2 people in the reservation, except that it publishing the results four times instead of just once.

Echo of results should be:

**Total for Options:** $94

Instead, the echo is:

**Total for Options:** $94

**Total for Options:** $94

**Total for Options:** $94

**Total for Options:** $94

Here's the associated query and PHP code:

```
    $optquery = "SELECT t.ibtp, c.ibt
                FROM clients c, tourprices t 
                WHERE c.tourstart = t.tourstart
                AND c.tourbk_id = t.tour_id"; 

    $optresult = $db->query($optquery); 

    while ($optrate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($optresult))
       {

     $opttotalcost = $optrate['ibtp'] * $optrate['ibt']; 
        echo '<strong>',"Total for Options :</strong>  $ {$opttotalcost}<br />"; 
}
```

Any one see the problem?

Comment: When you run the query by itself, does it give the result you expect?

Comment: r u sure what is in database ?

Comment: I think your query might be responding with 4 outputs. Super quick fix for this problem would be to put the echo outside of the while loop. But I think you have a different problem that should be addressed.

Comment: in tourprice table within ibtp is the price 47.  In the client table (currently there's just one row for testing purposes) within ibt is the number 2 (for 2 persons).  2 x $47 = $94 .. so, the math is correct.

Comment: Putting echo outside the while loop worked.  - thanks.  What do you suspect (think, believe, would check, etc) as the cause or problem that should be addressed?

Comment: Besides the join conditions of your two tables I don't see where you are limiting the results by, say, tour id or client id.

Comment: It would help if you could share the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE clients` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE `tourprices`.

Comment: @Jack the two tables are quite extensive but the clients table has tourstart_id, tourbk_id, tourstart, name, ibt, ibt_shared ... and more (of which were not used in this test).  The tourprices table has tourprice_id, tour_id, tourstart, ibtp, and others of which were not used in this test run.  perhaps the two 'tourstart' columns ... one in clients and one in tourprices?

Comment: You could expand your query for debugging purposes and print other columns from both tables, such as `clients.name` and `tourprices.tourprice_id`; that should tell you where those "extra" rows come from.

Comment: ah, I found the cause (the number of repeats directed my attention).  I added in roomtype to the $optquery, removed "distinct" [to test] and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have four identical (for those columns) rows in your database. Try using `SELECT DISTINCT`, as follows:

```
$optquery = "SELECT DISTINCT t.ibtp, c.ibt
                FROM clients c, tourprices t 
                WHERE c.tourstart = t.tourstart
                AND c.tourbk_id = t.tour_id";
```

Comment: Thanks.  This and the comment above to put the echo outside the while loop (aka move the ending curly brace to position before the echo) worked.    I checked but only have one IBT column and one IBTp column.  Will SELECT DISTINCT protect against what ever is causing this error?

Comment: though it probably shouldn't, I do have an IBT_Shared column in addition to just IBT.  Would this be an issue despite it not querying IBT% ?

Comment: @shane This answer will just hide the problem; it's important to find out why you're getting more results than you expect, otherwise over time this will explode and you have no idea why your database is slowing down.

Comment: I agree with Jack, you should probably check into this. But depending on what the table is DOING, there are entirely innocuous reasons for there to be four identical rows in a joined result like this. It's not about duplicated COLUMNS, it's about duplicated ENTRIES.

If you want, post more information about what the tables are doing -- what information are they actually storing? And we MAY be able to tell you whether this is a likely issue or a likely nonissue.